# Что нужно для запуска jar-файлов?

Tags: java, jar

Разработал программу. Скомпилировал файл *.jar у себя. Передаю этот файл знакомому. Что должно быть установлено на компьютере знакомого, чтобы этот файл у него запустился?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Runtime Environment подходящей версии